# Update Particular Part of a column through data of another column

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to my sql I am trying to update my column b_id by getting the value from date1 column the b_id is longtext the date1 is dateTime type

```
SELECT date1,b_id, DATE_FORMAT(date1'%Y/%m/%d') AS tostore
FROM tbl1 WHERE 
b_id = 'ID/2018/5/13/000111' 
OR
b_id = 'ID/2018/5/13/000222'
```

current data

```
date1            b_id                        tostore
2018-12-20      ID/2018/5/13/000111         2018/12/20
2018-10-30      ID/2018/5/13/000222         2018/10/30
```

I wanted TO USE the tostore COLUMN IN b_id but if I use this I wont keep any data of b_id I want the ID/ and the last g digits to remain the same I will really appreciate any advice thank you

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET b_id = DATE_FORMAT(date1,'%Y/%m/%d') WHERE 
    b_id = 'ID/2018/5/13/000111' 
    OR
    b_id = 'ID/2018/5/13/000222';

 Desired Output

 date1            b_id                        tostore
2018-12-20      ID/2018/12/20/000111         2018/12/20
2018-10-30      ID/2018/10/30/000222         2018/10/30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function of mysql to get the desired column value like below.

`CONCAT` combines the given set of string in the given order.

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` captures a part of text. Passing `-1` as last parameter helps to capture the id digit part of the `b_id` column by capturing from right.

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET b_id = CONCAT('ID/', DATE_FORMAT(date1,'%Y/%m/%d'), '/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(b_id, '/', -1))  
WHERE 
    b_id = 'ID/2018/5/13/000111' 
    OR
    b_id = 'ID/2018/5/13/000222';
```

Hope this helps.